# rails 3, will_paginate over existing limited active record result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm having a big problem with will paginate.

I have a query defined as scope in my model:

```
scope :published_and_valid, joins(...).where(...)
```

In my controller I sometimes just want to have the top 20.

```
.limit(20)
```

Now I want to be able to paginate over these 20 results (5 per page)

And I try to do this:

```
@articles = Article.published_and_valid.limit(20).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

This does not work as the result in my view is a pagineted result for ALL articles

Comment: What version of will_paginate do you have installed? (If in doubt, check your `Gemfile.lock`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like will_paginate imposes its own `limit` clause on your relation in order to do the paging. After some experimentation, the easiest way I could find to do this is to do eager-loading of the result set and use the functionality contained in [the array extensions](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/array.rb#files) to do the actual pagination.

Here's a quick example; note that you have to require `will_paginate/array`; you may wish to do this in an initializer or somewhere else. Note that it does monkey-patch `Array` to have the `paginate` method.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.published.limit(20).all # call `all` to eager load
    @articles = @articles.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
end
```

**[Update]**

Another option is to pass in the `total_entires` option to will_paginate based on the result set size.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.published.limit(20)
    @articles = @articles.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :total_entries => @articles.count)
  end
end
```

You can't pass in 20 as you can't guarantee that a full 20 results will be returned; by passing in the `count` attribute, you can ensure that the pagination will be correct.

Comment: ty brandon works like a charm, that was what i was searching for